# ¿Cómo adaptar una imagen de fondo en html a cualquier resolución?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```
html {
    background: url(images/1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Tengo este código para adaptar la imagen de fondo a cualquier resolución, sin embargo no se adapta, solo se adapta como yo quiero donde estoy realizando la página. Pero al abrir la página en otro tipo de resolución, no se adapta como yo deseo si no que se desordena por completo.

**¿Existe otro tipo de código que pueda usar para realizar esa acción?**

Comment: "_en otro tipo de resolución no se adapta si no que se desordena por completo_". ¿Podrías mostrar con una imagen a qué te refieres con eso?¿Cómo no se adapta?¿Y cómo quieres que se adapte?

Answer (score 3):

```css
html {
    background: url('http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

Prueba con

```
html {
    background: url(images/1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

En el siguiente enlace [puedes testear los valores `background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) y así ver cual es la que se adapte a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con este código, yo lo implemento sobre la etiqueta body:

```css
body{
  background: url(http://www.fondos7.net/wallpaper-original/wallpapers/naturaleza-y-rocas-10201.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```